# How to get the full path?

Tags: c#

Overall I am trying to take off the file name off the end of a path and display the rest of the path. 
For example this path:  C:\Users\Documents\Development\testing\11.0.25.10\AUW_11052_0_X.pts

I want to strip off the "AUW_11052_0_X.pts" file and only display "C:\Users\Documents\Development\testing\11.0.25.10\"

How exactly does one go about this? I'm not sure of how to make this into a regex pattern.

Heres my problem more detailed:

What I was going to do was create a regex function that took in two arguments, the original path then the file name (the program at some point loops through a list where all the files are stored and gets the file name from that) I was going to create a regex function that grabbed anything after the last "\" charachter and compared it with the file name argument. If it indeed matches than strip the file name off and if it doesnt then just leave it be. My problem is figuring out of how to do a regex pattern that finds anything after the last "\" charachter which I dont know how

ANSWER: I found the answer, and the pattern is `^(.*[\\\/])` this will grab every character up to the last "\"

Comment: Indeed, Regex is complete overkill for this.  Do as @SLaks suggested.

Answer (score 11):

You're looking for `Path.GetDirectoryName()`.

Comment: I did this and sadly it doesn't get the correct results I want. Since i'm looping through directories and files it will produce "C:\Users\Documents\Development\testing\" sometimes intead of "C:\Users\Documents\Development\testing\11.0.25.10\". That's why I wanted to check it with regex.

Comment: @user2619395: State your problem more precisely.  It sounds like you only want to call it if the path doesn't end in a slash.

Comment: My issue is that I am copying a source file to a directory file. At some point during my code I need only the directory the folder is coming out of. Which would be for example "C:\Users\Documents\Development\testing\11.0.25.10\". However, at some point it does loop through the "C:\Users\Documents\Development\testing\11.0.25.10\" directory since it goes through the original folder \11.0.25.10\ and it's subdirectories.

Comment: Long story short, I just want any file names cut off of the path, becuase in certain situatoins the Path.GetDirectoryName() will leave me with "C:\Users\Documents\Development\testing\" and not "C:\Users\Documents\Development\testing\11.0.25.10\"

Comment: @user2619395: How do you know what is a filename and what isn't?

Comment: Well... What I was going to do was create a regex function that took in two arguments, the original path then the file name (the program also at some point loops through a list where all the files are stored and gets the file name from that) I was going to create a regex function that grabbed anything after the last "\" charachter and compared it with the file name argument. If it indeed matches than strip the file name off and if it doesnt then just leave it be. My problem is figuring out of how to do a regex pattern that finds anything after the last "\" charachter which I dont know how.

Comment: "Long story short, I just want any file names cut off of the path" - that's **exactly** what `Path.GetDirectoryName()` does. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx) for all the gory details.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just do something like this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace directorysearch
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\users\documents\development\testing");
            FileInfo[] files = null;
            DirectoryInfo[] dirs = null;
            dirs = di.GetDirectories();
            foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in dirs)
            {
                files = dir.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to enter the base path (c:\users\documents\development\testing) and then manipulate each individual directory under that and then each individual file under each directory?